# How to install gcloud with pip in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, pip

I am trying to install gcloud in my window using Pip install gcloud. however I am facing below given error:

```
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zjeo9mnr\googleapis-common-protos\
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+%27_NamespacePath%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27sort%27

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make sure that you have `pip 9.0.1` or higher

you can check it from `pip3 --version` or `pip2 --version`

more info : [Gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup)